# How do I debug or set breakpoint to SSIS package for FTP task

Tags: sql, ssis

I have one SSIS package i was deployed on server now i need to debug that `SSIS package`

so i have downloaded that on my local machine but

> I'm not able to set breakpoints not on any step :(

nor able to compile or run why so getting error  like

```
Error : Failed to decrypt protected XML node "DTS:Property" with 
error 0x8009000B "Key 
not valid for use in specified state.". 
You may not be authorized to access this   information. This error occurs when there  
is a cryptographic error. Verify that the 
correct key is available.   C:\Users\Job1.dtsx  1   1
```

Package protection level sets to : EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey

Comment: It sounds like you didn't enter the correct password when opening the file. Double check that the password is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are not the user who saved/deployed the package. If the package is encrypted by saving sesative with user key then only that user will be able to run or debug the package properly. You need to change the package protection level to do not save sensitive and then rebuild it. Next you will need to re-enter the sensitive data such as FTP credentials, etc and then change the package protection level to Encrypt sensitive with password. You will then be able to debug the package.

If you deploy to MSDB, then it is always a good idea to choose the Rely on server storage for encryption. If you do this, then when you pull the package down from the package store, it will automatically encrypt using your user key and you can set the appropriate protection level without the pain